# code.google.com: git: fatal: remote error: Repository not found

Tags: git

I have created a new repository in `code.google.com`, generated the `code.google.com` password and updated my `~/.netrc` with

```
machine code.google.com login <email-id> password <password>
```

As per the instruction in the `code.google.com`, I was able to `clone` the repository using the following command:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/<repository-name>/
```

and after that I added some files to the repository and executed, `git add`, followed by `git commit`. But when I executed `git push origin master` it gave the following error

```
fatal: remote error: Repository not found
```

When google'ed for this issue, I found couple of links but the work-around that was mentioned in that didn't seem to work. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

UPDATE: 
I have tried the following work-arounds but unsuccessful:

1. Update the `url` in the `.git/config` to take `username` and `password`
2. Give the `username` and `password` in the `url` in the `git clone` command
3. Update `username` and `password` with global `git` config command

Comment: Please edit your question to include the workaround or any other solutions you've already tried. Otherwise, we may answer with one of these, providing no additional help!